# Access selected items of a ListBox that is within a DataTemplate

Tags: xaml, listbox, uwp

I am aking a UWP app and I have a Dynamic `Pivot` control in my XAML.
Inside the Pivot the PivotItem are populated using a `ListBox`. I want to be able to detect whenever a ListBox item is selected or deselected. But it seems that any control inside a `DataTemplate` cannot be referenced by name in the code-behind file.

So, I **cannot** do something like `MyListBox.SelectedItems`

Here's my XAML:

```
        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

        <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBox Name="MyListBox"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding List}"                            
                         SelectionMode="Multiple"
                         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                         SelectionChanged="FacetsListBox_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>                                       
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                           Text="{Binding read}"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding num}"   
                                               Grid.Column="1"/>    
                            </Grid>                               
                        </DataTemplate>                            
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.ItemTemplate>

    </Pivot>
```

Comment: You still can have that `FacetsListBox_SelectionChanged` handler in your code behind, even when the `ListBox` is within a template.

Comment: @JustinXL I cannot access `ListBox` from the code-behind

Comment: Inside that handler, `sender as ListBox` is the one you are looking for. :)

Comment: I might need some additional help.`var MyListBox = sender as ListBox;
            var selected = MyListBox.SelectedItems as ObservableCollection<IFacet>;` gives me null

Comment: Can you show me your code behind code?

Comment: @JustinXL updated

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? I am confused.

Comment: @JustinXL there are multiple pivot items and each pivot item has one ListBox. When the user selects the ListBoxItem of any ListBox, I want to store the selected object ( which I am able to do ). But I also want to differentiate between the selected items based on which pivot item ( or ListBox) it comes from.

Comment: I am still not sure what you mean by "difficientiate..." There's nothing in your code that helps me understand it either...

Comment: @JustinXL By differentiate I mean that I want to know that out of multiple ListBoxes, which `ListBox ` does the selected items belong to. Suppose there are two Pivot items, 1) Author 2) Language. Therefore, 2 Pivot item will be dynamically created, each pivot item will have one ListBox. Therefore, there will be two ListBoxes. Now, the user can select items from any of the two ListBoxes and I want to store all the seleted items (from both ListBoxes ) in a List<T>. But later I would like to iterate through the List and be able to tell that from which ListBox the item has come(Author or Language)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145434/discussion-between-justin-xl-and-ravi-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Behavior and use AssociatedObject to handle to the events of your ListBox I thinks is the easiest way to solve your problem